# Point to multiple servers with the same domain name

Tags: php, dns, hosting, web-hosting, velo

I am using 2 web servers (hosted) - one is for PHP scripts in GoDaddy, and the other one is Wix.

I would like both of them to point to the same domain name (without using sub-domains).
For example:

- `example.com/link1` - will point to a Wix page named "link1"
- `example.com/link2` - will point to a GoDaddy webpage

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please use link1.MyDomain.com and link2.MyDomain.com to point to two different servers instead.

Comment: I don't want to use this option (sub-domains)..

Comment: How would a DNS know to which server it should route the request? You'd have to use some form of Loadbalancer to do this, sitting before the actual servers...

Comment: @HonkderHase is right. An alternative to a load balancer would be to use one of the servers as front server which proxies requests to the second server hidden behind it. But you'd have to check if your hosting provider allows you to do that.

Comment: Route all requests to /link1/* to a script that fetches and outputs the content from the actual WIX URL at your main server/domain (GoDaddy). Basically just an address-masking proxy transcluding your Wix content. (Be aware that your Wix scripts may have domain-related opinions.) That'd be the simplest way to do it, however much simpler still would be to just use a subdomain for one/both.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use DNS alone to route different paths to different servers.  You have several options:

#### Use subdomains

Unlike paths, subdomains can point to different servers.  You could use DNS to point `wix.example.com` and `godaddy.example.com` do the respective hosting companies.  (Of course you are free to choose whatever names for the subdomains you want, I would not recommend using a hosting company name in a user facing URL).

#### Use a CDN

Content delivery networks (CDNs) typically have the ability to route different paths to different servers. CDNs are a proxy between your website and your users.  Users make requests to a local CDN edge node which will serve the content directly if it has it in its cache.  Otherwise they use routing rules to fetch the content from your origin servers.  Some CDNs even offer free service with a small number of routing rules.

#### Run your own reverse proxy

Another option would be to run your own reverse proxy.  For example you could point your domain to GoDaddy and put configuration in your `.htaccess` file to fetch `link2` from Wix. (Assuming you are using shared hosting and GoDaddy, you have access to `.htaccess`, and they allow reverse proxy configuration.)